# Seeking Efficient Approximation Algorithm for Adaptation of TSP

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, approximation, traveling-salesman

Consider the following adaptation of the traveling salesman problem:

> Given a complete, undirected graph $G$ with nonnegative edge weights,
>   color each vertex either red or blue. Find the shortest path that
>   visits all vertices exactly once (does not need to return to starting
>   vertex), but does not visit vertices of the same color more than 3
>   times in a row (i.e. the path
>
> $$red \to blue \to blue \to blue \to red$$
>
> is valid but
>
> $$red \to blue \to blue \to blue \to blue$$
>
> is not. Assume that there are the same number of red and blue
>   vertices.

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to at least *approximate* a shortest path given this constraint. My initial thought was the following (besides simply trying all $|V|!$ different paths):

**Greedy Approach:** Choose a starting vertex $v_0$ and at each step, simply choose the vertex $v_1$ that minimizes $d(v_0, v_1)$. However, keep a record of the colors of $v_{i}$, $v_{i-1}$, and $v_{i-2}$ at each step, and if the optimal choice of the next vertex $v_{i+1}$ violates the color constraint, choose the next best vertex.

The only problem I see with this is that you can 'run out' of vertices of a given color. That is, you could reach a point where there are more than $3$ vertices remaining, but they are all of the same color. This would make it impossible to complete the path.

**My Question**: Does anyone have any suggestions on algorithms to try? Maybe a modification to my suggested greedy approach to make it complete, or another paradigm all together?

*(I know that this problem is $NP$-complete - that's why I'm seeking an approximation algorithm.)*

Comment: Technically, this isn't NP-complete because it's not in NP: it's not a decision problem. It's also not immediately obvious that it's NP-hard. At least, I've not managed to reduce ordinary TSP to this problem after thinking about it for a couple of minutes.

Comment: "color each vertex" $\: \mapsto \:$ "with each vertex colored" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your exercise, it sounds like you are only looking for a hint or an approach.  So, here is a hint/approach.

Let $M$ be a DFA (deterministic finite-state automaton) that recognizes all legal sequences of colors, where a sequence is legal if it doesn't contain the same color three times in a row.

Construct a new, bigger graph $G'$, formed by a "product construction" of $G$ and $M$.  The number of vertices in $G'$ will be at most the number of vertices of $G$ times the number of states of $M$, so $G'$ will be bigger but not too much bigger.

Now think about what you can do with this $G'$.  Try translating your original problem into some question about $G'$.