# Shortest walk from $u$ to $v$ through $w$

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

We have an undirected, weighted graph $G=(V, E)$ with two weight functions
$W_1 : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $W_2 : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$
such that for every $e \in E$ we have $W_1(e) > W_2(e)$.

The length of a walk $\sigma$ is calculated in such a way that
for every edge $e \in E$, for the first appearance of $e$ in $\sigma$
we calculate the weight of $e$ by $W_1(e)$, and for reminding
appearances of $e$ in $\sigma$ we calculate the weight of $e$
by $W_2(e)$.

The goal is to find the shortest walk from $u$ to $v$ through $w$.
Is this problem $\mathsf{NP}$-hard?
If not, how can we find such a walk?

Comment: Since this problem is not a decision problem, it is not in $\mathsf{NP}$. Perhaps you want to consider the decision version of the problem?

Comment: I apologize, the mistake was corrected.

Comment: The shortest walk from $u$ to $v$ via $w$ consists of a shortest walk from $u$ to $w$ together with a shortest walk from $w$ to $v$.

Comment: If we choose a bit longer walk from u to w, then, might we can use the lightened edges more efficiently. So I think that the greedy algorithm can not find an optimal walk.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/146174/755

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89129/83244

Answer (score 1):

The shortest walk must have the form

```
u
 \
  t<->w
 /
v
```

where the edges in each arrow are disjoint. To see this, suppose in the shortest walk, we go through nodes $u_1'=u,\ldots,u_{k'}',u_1,\ldots,u_k=w$ from $u$ to $w$, go through nodes $v_1=w,\ldots,v_l,v_1',\ldots,v_{l'}'=v$ from $w$ to $v$, where $v_1',\ldots,v_{l'}' \notin \{u_1',\ldots,u_{k'}',u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$, and $v_l=u_1$, like the following graph:

```
                  u    (u_1,...,u_k)
 (u_1',...,u_{k'}')\        /\
                    u_1(v_l)  w       The walk (u_1,...,u_k) may overlap with (v_1,...,v_l)
 (v_1',...,v_{l'}')/        \/
                  v    (v_1,...,v_l)
```

Now suppose edges $e_1,\ldots,e_h$ are shown in both the walk $(u_1,...,u_k)$ and the walk $(v_1,\ldots,v_l)$, and the remaining edges in both walks are $f_1,\ldots,f_p$ and $g_1,\ldots,g_q$ respectively. Then the cost of the walk $(u_1,...,u_k=v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^h (W_1(e_i)+W_2(e_i))+\sum_{i=1}^pW_1(f_i)+\sum_{i=1}^qW_1(g_i)\\
\ge{}&\sum_{i=1}^h (W_1(e_i)+W_2(e_i))+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^p(W_1(f_i)+W_2(f_i))+\sum_{i=1}^q(W_1(g_i)+W_2(g_i))\right).
\end{align*}
That is, the average cost of the walk $(u_1,\ldots,u_k,\ldots,u_1)$ and the walk $(v_l,\ldots,v_1,\ldots,v_l)$ is no more than that of the walk  $(u_1,...,u_k=v_1,\ldots,v_l)$. So the shortest walk must have the form shown in the first figure.

Now you can try every node as $t$ to compute the optimal walk from $u$ to $w$ to $v$. This is a polynomial-time algorithm.